# Torque from normal force on a sphere which rolls without slipping

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

Let's say that there is a solid sphere on a rough horizontal platform. There is a force exerted on it parallel to the ground, pushing it forward. It is rolling without slipping. Would the ground be exerting a torque on it? Would kinetic friction? Or would it only be gravity?

Comment: it is not kinetic friction, but static friction, because it is rolling and the point of contact does not slip

Comment: it a force makes torque or not depends on where you put your origin of coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the ground be exerting a torque on it?

Yes.

The force $F$ you mentioned causes (translational) acceleration $a$, by Newton 2L. But because you specify rolling without slipping there's also *angular acceleration* $\alpha=\frac{\text{d}\omega}{\text{d}t}$.

Rolling without slipping means ($R$ is the ball's radius):

$$v=\omega R$$

and after taking the time derivative:

$$a=\alpha R$$

Also by Newton 2L, the angular acceleration requires a torque, here provided by the friction force $F_f$, which points in the opposite direction of $F$ and acts on the contact point between the ball and the rough ground.

The torque $\tau$ is given by:

$$\tau=F_f R=I\alpha$$

with $I$ the moment of inertia of the ball.

[image: Friction on a ball]

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! Your explanation is fantastic. I'm still wondering, though, what it is which causes the torque to make the ball spin. Is it the friction from the platform, or perhaps contact with the platform, or maybe gravity?

Comment: *Is it the friction from the platform, or perhaps contact with the platform, or maybe gravity?* The normal force $N$ is a reaction to gravity ($mg$) and then gives rise to the friction force via the usual model $F_f=\mu N$ ($\mu$ is the friction coefficient). Hope this helps.

Comment: It does! Also, is it correct to say that because the Fn and Fg go directly through the center of mass, they don't produce a torque? Thanks again